# I was stored cookies in temp file on client machine for cross domain cookie issue. Is this right way to override on cross domain cookie issue?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, safari

Actually, I was suffered from cross domain cookie issue in safari web browser in mac & iPhone devices. 
                  So, I was create one temp file on client machine and save all cookies in that temp file for One domain. And when I  was try to read that cookies from another domain file then in that file i was made changes like if cookies are not set then fetch cookies data from that temp file And again set cookies for that domain. It's work successfully. but Is this right way to  overcome on that issue?.